# What does asterisk curly brace *{ mean when defining objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
projection = *{
  var projection = d3.geoOrthographic();
  while (true) {
    yield projection.rotate([Date.now() / 200, -20]);
  }
}
```

I have seen this in this tutorial
https://medium.com/@mbostock/a-better-way-to-code-2b1d2876a3a0

but it only runs for me if I use it without the asterisk "*"

```
projection = {
  var projection = d3.geoOrthographic();
  while (true) {
    yield projection.rotate([Date.now() / 200, -20]);
  }
}
```

What does the asterisk mean in this context for javascript?

Comment: Looks like `*{ … }` might be d3.express shorthand for `(function* () { … })()`, i.e. a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to python, the `function *` declares a generator function (notice the use of the keyword `yield` also). ~~This is suggested in ES5~~

Source: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*`

Comment: Except that there's no `function *` in OP's code. It's `projection = *{ ...`

Comment: Also, generators are *not* ES5